# Trouble Figuring Out Behavior of HTML page with Append Child

Tags: javascript, html

Recently I've been developing an application that allows a user to enter a stock symbol on a webpage and it returns some data from the Yahoo finance API. I can get the data fine and want to display it in a table. But right when I call appendChild it displays the data perfectly on the page and then in about a second it is gone! I figured I would post this question here since I've never seen anything like this before. Also the other strange thing that if I don't have the confirm message right after the appendChild line it seems like it doesn't even go to the callback method at all. Can anyone help me figure out what is going on and why my data shows up for a second and then is gone the next? Does this have something to do with the HTML tree?

Here is my complete code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Public Stock Ticker and Selection</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"</meta>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mashsheet.css">
        <div id="headerdiv">Diversified Stocks and Securities</b>
           <div id="imagediv">
              <img id="cnnimg" src="cnn.jpg" alt="Sorry" height="80" width="140"/img>
              <img id="appleimg" src="apple.jpg" alt="No Apple" height="100" width="120"/img>
                  <img id="microimg" src="microsoft.jpg" alt="No Micro" height="100" width="150"/img>
                  <img id="amaimg" src="amazon.jpg" alt="No amazon" height="70" width="200"/img>
                  <img id="nationimg" src="nationwide.jpg" alt="No nationwide" height="50" width="240"/img>
                  <img id="huntingtonimg" src="huntington.jpg" alt="No huntington" height="70" width="160"/img>
                  <img id="ciscoimg" src="cisco.gif" alt="No cisco" height="70" width="160"/img>
                  <img id="ibmimg" src="ibm.jpg" alt="No ibm" height="70" width="160"/img>
                </div>
           <p id="headdescription"> - A quick and easy place to find up to date stock information about your favorite companies!</p>
             </div>
</head>
<body>
<p>Enter the name of the stock you are interested in below and then click the submit button
     to get back a wealth of information including trades, gains, losses, and more.</b></p>
<form id="stockInput">
Stock Name: <input type="text" id="stockTextBox">
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit">
</form>
</b>

<table id="stocktable"
<tr> <th scope="col">Stock Name</th>
     <th scope="col">Price</th>
     <th scope="col">Symbol</th>
     <th scope="col">Ts</th>
     <th scope="col">Type of Stock</th>
     <th scope="col">UTC Time</th>
     <th scope="col">Volume</th>
</tr>
<tr> <th id="name" scope="row"></th>
<th id="price" scope="row"></th>
<th id="symbol" scope="row"></th>
<th id="ts" scope="row"></th>
<th id="typeofstock" scope="row"></th>
<th id="utctime" scope="row"></th>
<th id="volume" scope="row"></th>
</tr>     
</table>
<label id="stockLabel"></label>
<script>

var submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");
submitButton.addEventListener('click', actionPerformed, false);

function actionPerformed(e)
{
    var textValue = document.getElementById("stockTextBox").value;
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src',"http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/"+textValue+"/quote?format=json&callback=myCallBack");

    document.body.appendChild(script);
    confirm("You got information for " + textValue + "stock!");
 }
 function myCallBack(data)
 {

   document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = data.list.resources[0].resource.fields.name;
   document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = data.list.resources[0].resource.fields.price;
   document.getElementById("symbol").innerHTML = data.list.resources[0].resource.fields.symbol;
   document.getElementById("ts").innerHTML = data.list.resources[0].resource.fields.ts;
   document.getElementById("typeofstock").innerHTML = data.list.resources[0].resource.fields.type;
   document.getElementById("utctime").innerHTML = data.list.resources[0].resource.fields.utctime;
   document.getElementById("volume").innerHTML = data.list.resources[0].resource.fields.volume;

 }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit">
```

This is a submit button. When you press a submit button and don't cancel it, it submits the page. Your `<form>` does not have an *action*, therefore the current *URI* is used. Your `<form>` does not have a *method*, therefore *GET* is used. Your `<input>` does not have a *name*, therefore all you see change is a `?` added to the *URI*.

Comment: Can't believe i missed that. Good eye. Maybe it should changed it to a regular button.

Comment: or simply cancel the event in your listener.

Comment: I changed it to a regular button type and it worked like it was supposed to all along. Wow, that was a boneheaded move to put a submitButton there in that circumstance. I guess I'll know in the future. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Tastybrownies— A submit button might be handy if the script fails - the form submits and you deal with it at the server. Otherwise, the user sees nothing. If the script runs properly, just cancel the submit.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the confirmation message in a timeout...

```
document.body.appendChild(script);
setTimeout(function(){
    confirm("You got information for " + textValue + "stock!");
}, 0);
```

Comment: Actually putting this code in made the information not show up in the table at all for some reason. Good try though.

Comment: What browser and version are you testing on?